# CSS Add a rounded sticker in a div corner with image inside

Tags: html, css

I have the following block in html page:

```
* {
  margin: 0px; 
  padding: 0px; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 body, html {
  height: 100%;
 }

.container-form {
  width: 100%;  
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

.wrap-form {
  width: 500px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 42px 55px 45px 55px;
}

<div class="container-form">
  <div class="wrap-form">
    <form> ... </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I want to add a rounded sticker with an image inside at the top right.

I created the following div in wrap-form:

```
.sticker {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  right:10px;
}
img {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
}
<div class="sticker">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="alt" />
</div>
```

But the image is outside of the form... Do you have an idea why ?

EDIT: see the code here: https://codepen.io/Old_Krupnik/pen/qBENRWL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just need to add a relative position property to your .wrap-form class as below:

```
.wrap-form {
  width: 500px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 42px 55px 45px 55px;
  position: relative;
}


.sticker {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  right:10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it is not working properly. See the code I made : https://codepen.io/Old_Krupnik/pen/qBENRWL

Comment: I edited you code and this works:

    .sticker {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      overflow: hidden;
      position:absolute;
      top:10px;
      right:10px;
     }
    .sticker img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%
     }

Comment: Wow, thank you, this is definitely better but I was wondering if it is possible that the sticker was half inside the white block and half outside the white block ?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp,

> `position: absolute`: The element is positioned relative to its first positioned **(not static)** ancestor element

Your form and any default element is by default **have `position: static` set**. So if you wish to position your sticker **relative to the form**, you need to add the property `postion: relative` to that form element *(and of course `position: absolute` to the sticker)*.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the child element to stay within the restraints of its parent, its parent needs to have its position set to relative and the child to absolute. Please see code below:

```css
.parent {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  
  /* The below is important */
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  background: blue;
  
  /* The below is important */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button class="child">Foo</button>
</div>
```